# Mounting Remote Filesystem over SSH as a Different User

Tags: ssh, filesystems, remote, mount, sshfs

Due to a breach of security, the administrators of the work server have implemented a new method of security.  To log into the server, we must log in as our own user (which has severely limited permissions), then `su` into another user under which we can do development (which we cannot log in to from the outside).

It used to be that we just logged in to a common user which had permissions, and I could simply mount the remote filesystem right onto my local filesystem using `sshfs`.  Now that we have to `su` into another user, I can't simply mount it like I have before.

I've done a reasonable amount of research and tried all "solutions" I found.  I've been trying to make this work for some time.

My question is: is there a way to `su` into a different user inside a `sshfs` mount?  Perhaps running a script on the server after the mount completes or something?

I would use something like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/158392/how-do-i-sudo-over-sshfs), but I don't have `sudo` access on the server, only `su`.

As a side note, my development computer is running LM11, and I'm mounting a share on some old Red Hat server.

Answer (score 2):

sshfs supports specifying the sftp server to use. So copy the normal sftp binary to some path (like the home dir), setuid the binary with `chmod u+s`, and pass `-o sftp_server=/path/to/sftp` to sshfs.

Example, devuser is the shared account, and myuser is your account

```
devuser@remote # cp `which sftp` ~/
devuser@remote # chmod u+s ~/sftp
myuser@local # sshfs myuser@remote:/mount/source /mount/point -o sftp_server=/home/devuser/sftp
```

You'll want to lock it down though, so do something like `chmod 750 /home/devuser` and make sure your user is in the group owning /home/devuser. You could also copy the sftp binary to your own directory and lock your home directory down.